# Swiftui: how to watch variable binded to text field always

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using Swift-UI for creating my app. 
There is an `AccountView` is listing user's attributes and you can update it.

Once you click an `Update` button on the user's variable row of the list, navigate to `EditVariableView`, where you can change the variable with `Text Field`.

Of course, the text field has a validation of the inputted text, and you can commit the change by the `Submit` button on the right-up corner of `EditVariableView`.

For validation of the input, I use `onCommit`, detecting the change of the input, but here is a problem.

When you touch the text field, the keyboard comes out, and also you can input the text. But `onCommit` emits an event only when you close the keyboard.

If you input the text and click the `Submit` button without closing the keyboard, certainly `onCommit` does not emit an event for the validation.  So, of course, the validation won't be done.

I want you to tell me, how to detect the input change on every text change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Submit button if TextField is in editing state

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var txt: String = ""
    @State var editingFlag = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("text", text: $txt, onEditingChanged: { (editing) in
                self.editingFlag = editing
            }) {
                print("commit")
            }.padding().border(Color.red)
            Button(action: {
                print("submit")
            }) {
                Text("SUBMIT")
            }.disabled(editingFlag)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SwiftUI 2.0

With the Xcode 12 and from iOS 14, macOS 11, or any other OS contains SwiftUI 2.0, there is a new modifier called 'onChange' that detects any change of the given `state` and can be performed on any view. So with some minor refactoring:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var txt: String = ""
    @State var editingFlag = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("text", text: $txt)
                .onChange(of: txt) {
                    print("Changed to :\($0)")
                }
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.red)

        Button("SUBMIT") {
            print("submit")
        }
        .disabled(editingFlag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from:  hacking with with Swift. Paul Hudson

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var name = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter your name:", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .onChange(of: name) { newValue in
                print("Name changed to \(name)!")
            }
    }
}
```